# Dropdown List Foreign Key Django

Tags: python, django

Good day. I have something to ask.

I have Student Model and in that student model I have foreign key Address, What I'm asking is I want to create a dropdown list from foreign key Address in the seperate dropdown list except for zip_code like the picture below:

```
Student(models.Model):
    ...
    ....
    Address = models.Foreignkey(Address)

Address(models.Model):
    zip_code = models.CharField(...)
    city = model.Charfield(..)
    province= model.Charfield(..)
    country= model.Charfield(..)
```

Thank you.[check here the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZIfO.jpg)

Comment: What are the fields in Address Model ? Add Address Model also for clear

Comment: this is my complete Address model.

class Address(models.Model):
    country = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
   province = models.Charfield(max_length=200)
  zip = models.Charfield(null=True, blank=True, max_length=7, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^d(1,10}$')])
  city = models.Charfield(max_length=200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In views.py loop through the student object as follows:

```
<select id="city">
{% for address in object.address_set.all %}
<option value={{address.city}}>{{address.city}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

<select id="province">
{% for address in object.address_set.all %}
<option value={{address.province}}>{{address.province}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>

<select id="country">
{% for address in object.address_set.all %}
<option value={{address.country}}>{{address.country}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: id like to know what im gonna do in my views.py

Comment: just return the student object